# Java Nifi Processor with Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, jpa, apache-nifi, entitymanager, hibernate-jpa

I'm trying to use a hibernate JPA from my custom Nifi processor written in Java. 
From inside the processor i don't have any information about connection string, username, password etc (because in the Nifi it is defined in a separated service). But i have a ready java.sql.Connection object.

```
DBCPService dbcpService = context.getProperty(DB_CONNECTION_POOL).asControllerService(DBCPService.class);
Connection con = dbcpService.getConnection();
```

Now i would need somehow to get an EntityManager (or DataSource) using only the Connection object without having db parameters. Is it possible?
Will appreciate help.

Comment: Asking for user1399759: "I know this is a pretty old question, but it's one of the few results that pops up on a Google search - did you happen to make headway on this issue? I'm looking at doing some complex object interaction with PostgreSQL through NiFi and would love to save some learning pains."

Answer (score 2):

Check out the comment on this (closed but not incorporated) [pull request](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/1417/files#r97923254), it implies you could create your own BasicDataSource impl but delegate to the DBCPService.getConnection() call.

Comment: Thank you. will try that